# How can you do this in CSS

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to do this in  CSS without using the float property;

I know how to add the icon but i'm not sure how to add the icon before the heading and paragraph.

[image]

Comment: What did you do so far? Paste your code here to get support.

Comment: I don't want the code.I can code Myself i just want to know the most standard effective way and i already figured out.

Comment: I understand that you code yourself, but if you are asking question in this style, then you will get down-votes (I did not vote down) and will never be able to build your reputation with stackoverflow. Also, when you figured out yourself, then post your answer to your question.

Comment: I figured out by other people helping me not by my self  and posting most effective ways without using tables or floats exactly what i asked. Big thanks to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTML5/CSS3 approach would be to use proper markup instead of 1999-style tables, and style them with a single flexbox reference:

```css
section {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure><img src="//placehold.it/150"></figure>
  <article>
    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Dolor sit amet etc. etc.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

An added advantage of this approach is that you can simply add `flex-direction:column` in a media query to make it responsive for small screens.

Comment: thanks a lot exactly what i asked this is truly most effective way without using old techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below:

```
.container img, .container div {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I like the flexbox approach better now that it's [universally acceptable](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) :)

Comment: Oooh, is it! Fantastic news. I can finally start learning it properly. Thanks for the heads up. I'll give your answer a plus one.

Comment: [Bookmark this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), all you'll ever need on the subject.

Comment: I've had that page bookmarked for what feels like about 18 months. I kept on having to hold back from reading it and practicing it because it never does to get _too_ far ahead of real-world browsers. I've been saving it for exactly this moment.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `inline-block` https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/

html

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
<div>
  <h2>
heading
</h2>
  <p>
    other text other text other text other text other text other text other text other text other text
  </p>
</div>
```

css

```
img,
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```